# Start a transaction for saving only

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I'm wondering what is the recomended way to proceed in the following scenario:

- Let's say I have a `ReportService` responsible for generating a report, uploading it, sending an email and saving it on database.
- While saving in database, it would update a lot of entities and I would like to rollback the whole thing in case something fails.

So it would be something like:

```
@Service
public class ReportService {

    public void generateReport() {

        var entities = entityRepository.findEntities();

        var file = getReportData(entities);

        var url = uploadFile(file);
        
        sendEmail(url);

        // If something goes wrong while save on entity, roll back everything
        for (var e : entities) {
           entityRepository.save(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So the options I know I have are:

- Annotate the method with `@Transactional`: I don't think this is a good idea because we would be mixing HTTP requests and workload with database transaction
- Creating a whole new service, something like `ReportSavingService`, and having a method to only save those entities: This would work I think but it seems strange to me having an specific service dealing with the same business logic I already have a service for, just to save it...

What I am wondering is if those are the solutions we have dealing with Spring Data or if there is an easy way to do something like:

```
        // ...
        sendEmail(url);

        // If something goes wrong while save on entity, roll back everything
        database.beginTransaction();
        for (var e : entities) {
           entityRepository.save(e);
        }
        database.commit();
```

I know we have that kind of control going down a bit, using `EntityManager` directly, but then I cannot mix it with Spring Data's repositories methods... Can I?

Comment: Well, you *could* inject `TransactionTemplate` and use `transactionTemplate.execute(...)`, but I would suggest reconsidering the design - note that when you run irreversible actions first (sending the email), there's always the risk of the execution never reaching the persistence code. A better approach would be to generate the report, save it into the data store, and send the email *only after* the transaction succeeds (or, better still, have a separate job for sending pending reports via email)

Comment: Thanks @crizzis, yes, I do agree with your points. That's not a real case actually, just an example :) 
Will have a look at `TransactionTemplate`, didn't know it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html)

```java
@Autowired
TransactionTemplate tx;

// ...

    tx.execute(__ -> {
        for (var e : entities) {
           entityRepository.save(e);
        }
    }
```

I do agree with @crizzis comment that the design seems somewhat wrong, but I consider that somewhat besides the question.

Comment: Thanks @Jens, never heard of `TransactionTemplate`, will have a look at it!